# Make portion of UITextView unelectable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I dont want to allow user to select some part(few string) to be selectable. How to stop user from selecting that strings,User should not be able to bring the cursor in the middle of that string as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle it by impletation `UITextViewDelegate`'s `- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView`;